# How to read all parquet files from a s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently have an s3 bucket that has folders with parquet files inside. I want to read all the individual parquet files and concatenate them into a pandas dataframe regardless of the folder they are in.

I am trying the following code:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

pandas_dataframe = pq.ParquetDataset('s3://vivienda-test/2022/11', filesystem=s3).read_pandas().to_pandas()
print(pandas_dataframe)
```

I realize that it only works for concatenation the parquets of a specific folder of the bucket and it also gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/inf.py", line 5, in <module>
    pandas_dataframe = pq.ParquetDataset('s3://vivienda-test/2022/11', filesystem=s3).read_pandas().to_pandas()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py", line 1790, in __init__
    self.validate_schemas()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py", line 1824, in validate_schemas
    self._schema = self._pieces[0].get_metadata().schema
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py", line 1130, in get_metadata
    f = self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py", line 1137, in open
    reader = self.open_file_func(self.path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py", line 1521, in _open_dataset_file
    return ParquetFile(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.reader.open(
  File "pyarrow/_parquet.pyx", line 1227, in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetReader.open
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 100, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Parquet file size is 0 bytes
```

can someone help me?, thanks

Comment: Are you using `spark`, if yes then this can be done very easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aws wrangler api's to achieve the same.

https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.read_parquet.html

```
#Reading all Parquet files under a prefix
import awswrangler as wr
df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path='s3://bucket/prefix/')
```